# Porque com arrow functions o contexto é diferente de uma função comum?

Tags: javascript

No snippet que preparei abaixo, tenho uma tabela com alguns dados simples. Abaixo da tabela, há duas labels que contabilizam a idade total dos dados na tabela. A primeira label é calculada usando uma função anônima comum, a segunda, é usando uma arrow function.

Percebi, que na arrow function, o `this` é `Window`, e não o objeto que chamou a função, como no outro caso. Devido a isso, a soma na label resulta em NaN (Not a Number)

Lendo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), cheguei ao conceito de `this` léxico, mas a partir daí já não entendi mais nada. Como poderia contornar a situação para que a arrow function funcione da maneira que eu esperava nesses casos?

```js
window.onload = function (){
  atualizaSomaIdades();
  atualizaSomaIdadesArrowFunction();
}

$('.excluir').click(function (){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  atualizaSomaIdades();
  atualizaSomaIdadesArrowFunction();
});

function atualizaSomaIdades(){
  var total = 0;
  var rows = $('table').find('tbody').find('tr');
  rows.each(function () {
      total += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
  });
  $('#idade-comum').text(total);
}

function atualizaSomaIdadesArrowFunction(){
  var total = 0;
  var rows = $('table').find('tbody').find('tr');
  rows.each(() => {
    total += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
  });
  $('#idade-arrow-function').text(total);

}
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.negrito{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
    <td>Ações</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      João
    </td>
    <td>
      25
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="excluir">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Carlos
    </td>
    <td>
      16
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="excluir">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Artur
    </td>
    <td>
      21
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="excluir">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<span class="negrito">Total de idade:</span>
<span id="idade-comum"></span>
<span id="idade-arrow-function"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

O `this` léxico na *arrow function* é muito útil quando se trabalha orientado a objeto no javascript (com classes por exemplo). O exemplo da MDN é bem prático:

```
function Pessoa(){
  this.idade = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.idade++; // |this| corretamente referência ao objeto Pessoa
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Pessoa();
```

Para o seu caso, para que `this` não pegue um contexto mais global mas sim o local da função, você pode indicar o elemento alterando dessa forma:

```
rows.each((index,elemento) => {
```

**Exemplo**

```js
window.onload = function (){
  atualizaSomaIdades();
  atualizaSomaIdadesArrowFunction();
}

$('.excluir').click(function (){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  atualizaSomaIdades();
  atualizaSomaIdadesArrowFunction();
});

function atualizaSomaIdades(){
  var total = 0;
  var rows = $('table').find('tbody').find('tr');
  rows.each(function () {
      total += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
  });
  $('#idade-comum').text(total);
}

function atualizaSomaIdadesArrowFunction(){
  var total = 0;
  var rows = $('table').find('tbody').find('tr');
  rows.each((index,elemento) => {
    total += parseInt($(elemento).find('td').eq(1).text());
  });
  $('#idade-arrow-function').text(total);

}
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.negrito{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Idade</td>
    <td>Ações</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      João
    </td>
    <td>
      25
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="excluir">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Carlos
    </td>
    <td>
      16
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="excluir">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Artur
    </td>
    <td>
      21
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="excluir">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<span class="negrito">Total de idade:</span>
<span id="idade-comum"></span>
<span id="idade-arrow-function"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar o conceito de closures para obter uma referência direta ao `this`do contexto externo à sua arrow function.

Basta capturar o `this` em uma variável e utilizar essa variável dentro da arrow function.

```
const self = this
rows.each(() => {
  total += parseInt($(self).find('td').eq(1).text());
});
```

Ou você pode usar uma `function` normal, que você mesmo viu que captura o `this` automaticamente.

Caso você queria aprender mais sobre closures:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

Adicionando às respostas anteriores, você pode usar o método `bind` para determinar o contexto de `this` para funções:

```
rows.each((() => { total += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()); }).bind(this));
```

[Doc no Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

O método `bind` recebe como primeiro argumento um objeto chamado `thisArg`, que é o contexto para as chamadas de `this` dentro desta função. Assim, colocando `.bind(this)` em uma arrow function faz com que todos os `this` internos sejam iguais ao `this` externo do escopo dessa função.